# exporting and importing multiple files with commonjs

Tags: typescript

this is my first library called "things":

```
//animals.ts
module Animals {
    export class Cat {
        public name = "cat";
    }

    export class Dog {
        public name = "dog";
    }
}

export = Animals;


//houses.ts
module Houses {
    export class Big {
        public name = "big";
    }

    export class Small {
        public name = "small";
    }
}

export = Houses;
```

Now I want to import this two modules into a second library.
How should I set the package.json of my first library?
What should be the main and typings values?

I created a new file named index.ts:

```
import Animals = require("./animals");
import Houses = require("./houses");

export var animals = Animals;
export var houses = Houses;
```

and then I import it like this in the second library:

```
import { animals } from "things";
```

Is this correct? whats the best approach to solve this?

Comment: If you are doing node js, you don't need use the TypeScript internal modules aka namespaces. Just export the classes without the module {} wrapper and without the exports = Animals.

Comment: I had the same doubt in ReactJS, and can be used as follows
`export const Cat = require('.Cat').default`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
import Animals = require("./animals");
import Houses = require("./houses");

export var animals = Animals;
export var houses = Houses;
```

I would do :

```
export import Animals = require("./animals");
export import Houses = require("./houses");
```

As this exposes it both in the *variable* and the *type* declaration space ([more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html)). Other than that